# Issue accessing queryParams with GoRouter in Flutter app after recent update

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I'm encountering an issue with accessing `queryParams` in my Flutter app while using the GoRouter package for routing. It seems that a recent update has caused a change in how `queryParams` can be accessed from a route at the point of definition. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
final _router = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: OnBoardingScreen.route(),
        name: OnBoardingScreen.route(),
        builder: (context, state) {
          return OnBoardingScreen(
            next: state.queryParameters['next'],
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Previously, I could access `queryParams` directly from the state. However, after the recent update, `queryParams` seems to be inaccessible from the state.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update [10.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/changelog#1000) introduced some breaking changes, one of them is the removal of `queryParameters` getter from `GoRouterState`.

> **BREAKING CHANGE**:
>
> - Replaces location, queryParameters, and queryParametersAll in GoRouterState with Uri.
> - See [Migrating to 10.0.0](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vjupshmFJtfGSOppZxp7Tzkq7dotcLxCcpdluuNYe1o/edit?resourcekey=0-aS66t4OcDTjJW50s-veSzQ) or run `dart fix --apply` to fix the breakages.

The full URI of the route is in the [`uri`](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/GoRouterState/uri.html) property of the state, which includes the query parameters. You can access it with the [`queryParameters`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/queryParameters.html) getter of the `Uri` class like this:

```dart
state.uri.queryParameters['next']
```